# How to use regex to capture list of space delimited words?

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex to capture a list of space delimited words, but I am having trouble. Here is the regex that I am currently using:

```
((\w+)(?: ))*
```

alligator smith boy apple -> (alligator, smith, boy)

mouse rat -> (mouse, rat)

fish -> ()

I am using Python by the way to process this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're making this more difficult than it needs to be.  Why not just do this:

```
re.findall(r'\w+', s)
```

...or this:

```
re.split(r'\s+', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((\w+)(?: |$))*
```

Test for possible end of string.

**or** append a single space to the end of your string before testing.

Comment: See the alternative I posted in the answer.